# saving image in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am loading an image from an API in my tableviewcell, it downloads the image everytime I scroll down the UITableView. So what is the best way to save this image and so it doesn't have to download the image again if it is already there?

Same thing for text, how can I save the text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not very big, you can download it once and save it into user preferences (`NSUserDefaults`) as `NSData` object. Works for me.

Alternatively, you can use asynchronous requests with `NSUrlConnection` and implement caching in any way you like. (For example, update image only once a week.)
Moreover, even default cache settings of `NSUrlConnection` might work good enough.
[More on caching](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-169425)

**edit**
An example of asynchronous request.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
URLConnectionDelegate *delegate = ...;

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                            delegate:delegate];

if (!connection) {
  // something went wrong
}
```

In delegate, you mainly need methods to handle received data and to finish connection.
Assume you have `NSMutableData *receivedData` object.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  // success, do whatever you want with data

  [receivedData release];
  [connection release];
}
```

The link above and [API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection) provide more details about delegate structure.

Comment: @EquinoX I store many images of 3-5kb. But the whole thing about 'big' is my speculation: I *assume* that `NSUserDefaults` isn't supposed to hold large binary objects. And in any case, you can always store images in file system as well.

Comment: I think with API's and UITableView, it's better to use asynchrounous requests... I have no idea how to do so though.. can you point out to some more references.. google doesn't have too many of those

Comment: And also is it just image that usually people cache? Or is text considered to be cached as well

Comment: @EquinoX For url connection, response is cached: this specific type of response is not important. As for asynchronous requests, I'll update my post with an example, since I can't find any simple one on the web.

Comment: If I have a method that does the connection, which returns an NSString. Then how can I preserve that as now the result is on the delegate?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the LazyTableImages sample application in the iOS site sample code section. It has a great example of how to download images for a table cell using NSUrlConnection asynchronous calls and storing the images (and text) in an NSMutableArray.

> This sample demonstrates a multi-stage
>   approach to loading and displaying a
>   UITableView. It begins by loading the
>   relevant text from an RSS feed so the
>   table can load as quickly as possible,
>   and then downloads the images for each
>   row asynchronously so the UI is more
>   responsive.